# jquery ajax - how to handle the json response

Tags: jquery

This is the response to my ajax call. I want to handle each array element to update the title of a corresponding button on my page that has the value of the Letter element. I need to replace the alert(response); with a loop over the json array.

{"COLUMNS":["PAGESNUM","LETTER"],"DATA":[["372","A"],["922","B"],["779","C"],["3‌​78","D"],["132","E"],["353","F"],["551","G"],["591","H"],["6","I"],["340","J"],["‌​261","K"],["314","l"],["837","M"],["88","N"],["120","O"],["303","P"],["14","Q"],["‌​355","R"],["762","S"],["235","T"],["12","U"],["44","V"],["581","W"],["49","Y"],["‌​19","Z"]]}

```
$.ajax({
    type: "Get",
    url: "cfc/basic.cfc?method=CountUsersByLetter&returnformat=json",
    data: "nbw=" + nbw,
    datatype: "html",
    success: function (response) {
        //usercount = parseInt(response.substring(0, 10));
        ///$(_$this.target).attr('title', usercount);
        alert(response);
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('errorThrown');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

javascript is case sensitive, so you're going to want to make that parameter `dataType` and if you're getting JSON back, then don't tell jQuery that you're expecting "html"

```
 dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        alert(response.DATA[0][1]);//should alert "A"
    }
```

If you need to do some looping, your arrays are `response.COLUMNS` and `response.DATA` (which is an array of arrays).

```
var numCols = response.COLUMNS.length;
for( var i = 0; i < numCols; i++ ){
    response.COLUMNS[i]
}
```

or to loop over the nested array

```
var numData = response.DATA.length;
for( var i = 0; i < numData; i++ ){
    for( var j = 0; j < response.DATA[i].length; j++ ){
        response.DATA[i][j]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have many arrays in the JSON output. For example you could loop through the `DATA` property which is an array of arrays:

```
success: function (response) {
    $.each(response.DATA, function(index, elements) {
       // for each element in the DATA array get the 
       // coupes number and letter which are respectively the first
       // and second elements
       var number = elements[0];
       var letter = elements[1];
       ...
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to test your solution, but I can't get past a javascript format problem. Even after using jsbeautify the script is disabled on the page.

Comment: Who the heck are you? Where do you get off?

Comment: @gdoron See if you can figure out this solution. FOCUS! Being a nitwit, it will take you a while.